Type P MOSFET to switch voltage bus
I'm working on a project where I'm using the NTE0505MC (5V, 200mA) component to generate an isolated 5V output. Connected to the output of the NTE0505 are several components, and a Schottky diode is used to prevent the 5V output from feeding back into the USB power line.

Current Problem
When the NTE0505 is active and generating a 5V output, if the USB connector is also plugged in, both ends of the Schottky diode are at 5V, creating a problematic situation on the diode. This can lead to inefficiencies or malfunctions in the circuit.
Proposed Solution
To address this issue, I want to use a P-type MOSFET that acts as a switch. The idea is for the MOSFET to disconnect the 5V from the USB when the 5V output from the NTE0505 is active.

Operation
When the NTE0505 is active:

The 5V output from the NTE0505 is present.
The gate of the P-type MOSFET is connected to the output of the NTE0505, so it has 5V.
When the gate of the MOSFET has 5V, the MOSFET is off, isolating the USB power line.
The 5V from the USB does not pass through the MOSFET, preventing any interference.

When the NTE0505 is inactive:

The 5V output from the NTE0505 is not present.
The gate of the MOSFET is at a low potential (connected to GND through a resistor), so the MOSFET is on.
The 5V from the USB powers the components.

Consideration

Gate Resistor: it is necessary a resistor between the gate of the MOSFET and GND to helps the MOSFET turns off when the NTE0505 is inactive?
MOSFET Selection: can the IRLML6402 component be suitable?

Has anyone tried a similar solution or have any suggestions? I would appreciate any feedback or advice!
Thank you very much!

When the MOSFET is supposed to be on, it's feeding the 5V USB to it's own gate, turning it off. So there's a flaw in the logic there...

@Unimportant Thank you for your reply and for pointing out the obvious, I apologise for the 'silly' mistake. Could there be another way around the problem?

Draw yourself a controlled switch diagram to show sources and loads with specs. Then state your issue.

@Alinik I would be thinking along the lines of having the input voltage of the NTE0505 send a signal trough a optocoupler to turn that FET on and off.

You don't say what the 1μF capacitor is for. It seems redundant, but really should be at the output side, to be of any use.
You seem to be happy for the load to receive only 4.5V or so (due to the diode "eating" half a volt) when powered from USB, so I assume you'll be OK if the same thing happens when the DC-DC converter is powering the system. In that case, this is fine:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If you are concerned that the output voltage \$V_{OUT}=+4.5V\$ is too low, then that concern is presumably valid regardless of which power source is active, in which case you'll need some kind of active switching on both paths, requiring at least two transistors.
It's unclear what you want to happen in the situation where both sources are active, so the first thing to do is specify which source should be "on" when that happens. Once this is clearly defined, then you can proceed with the design process, making sure to never switch both transistors on simultaneously, which would effectively join the two supplies together.

I solved the problem by using a Smart Diode Controller like this one:

Here there is the datasheet of the AP74700Q:
https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/115/AP74700Q-3084900.pdf
Thank you all for your answers and suggestions.
